# Calculate moving sum/count by time condition using window function and filter PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, moving-average

I want to calculate the sum 29 previous days in the 30th-day row, I use filter and window function but the `FILTER` not work,

it still sums from the beginning to the end if I use:

```
Select *, Sum(quantity) filter (where time between time - interval '29 day' and time) over ()
from t1
```

it show null column if I use:

```
Select *, Sum(quantity) filter (where time between time - interval '29 day' and time - interval '1 day') over ()
from t1
```

---

Data, I reduce columns for simplicity

```
Time        sum_quantity
2020-01-01  1
2020-01-02  2
2020-01-03  3
2020-01-04  6
    ....
2020-01-30  100
```

Data type: Time is date and quantity is integer

Desired result:
Should have the same column as first table and add this moving sum column

**Day 30 = total quantity of day 1 to day 29, for every 30 days**

How to fix this

Comment: Please share with us the whole query. Also please add what do you expect to get as final result ?

Comment: @VBoka I have edited

Comment: I still do not see the expected results... Also, please share with us the data types of this two columns in your t1 table

Comment: Please fix your data example because if time is date then Day1 is not really a good example. Add some regular date, it should not be too hard...

Comment: Edited as you said @VBoka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a window function with a window frame definition using `range`:

```
select t1.*,
       sum(quantity) over (order by time
                           range between interval '29 day' preceding and current row
                          ) 
from t1 ;
```

EDIT:

If you have data for all dates, you can use `rows`:

```
select t1.*,
       sum(quantity) over (order by time
                           rows between 29 preceding and current row
                          ) 
from t1 ;
```

EDIT II:

If you need to deal with missing days in older versions of Postgres that do not support `range`, then expanding the data is probably the simplest method:

```
select t1.*,
       sum(quantity) over (order by time
                           rows between 29 preceding and current row
                           ) 
from (select generate_series(min(t1.time), max(t1.time), interval '1 day') as dte
      from t1
     ) d left join
     t1
     on d.dte = t1.time;
```

You may want to filter out the additional rows:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             sum(quantity) over (order by time
                                 rows between 29 preceding and current row
                                 ) as running_sum
      from (select generate_series(min(t1.time), max(t1.time), interval '1 day') as dte
            from t1
           ) d left join
           t1
           on d.dte = t1.time
     ) t1
where t1.time is not null;
```

Comment: I run the query and it show error: any way to fix? `RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED`

Comment: It works @HaoHao : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5135cb727f0745422d2e63e96e37b8c8

Comment: @HaoHao . . . What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: `SELECT version()` it show ver `10.6` , on dbfiddle it show `12.4` @GordonLinoff

Comment: I try the First query with my 60 days consecutive data and it also sums from start to end..., so I don't know what that window `range between` is used for. I don't use `rows` in case of missing date @GordonLinoff

Comment: I will use `Range between` with `generate_series` because there will/might be more than one rows that have the day (because of another category column) so `Range` helps, thank you. And must using SQL ver 11 or above. Correct myself: `range between` can be use for every 30 days @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2):

Please, use condition in where caluse Because you use windows function it's like contional expression like:

```
SUM(<expression>) FILTER(WHERE <condition>)
SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <expression> END)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to my question right? please write full query.

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter (where)` clause is always true and empty `over()` clause is window spanned over all result set.

You should specify the window in `over` clause, not `filter` clause. Probably you need something like

```sql
sum(quantity) over (order by time rows between 29 preceding and current row)
```

or better `range between...`.

Comment: I don't wanna use row range because the Date time is matter @tomas, Any other way?

Comment: in case missing some date.

Comment: `rows` or `range` is *the* way to solve your problem. See Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want :

```
select m1.Time
       , (select sum(sum_quantity) 
          from mytable m
          where m.time between (m1.time - interval '29 day') and (m1.time)) sum_total
from mytable m1
group by m1.Time
order by m1.Time;
```

Or maybe this is better:

```
select m1.Time
       , sum(m.sum_quantity) 
from mytable m
     join mytable m1 on m.time between (m1.time - interval '29 day') and (m1.time)
group by m1.Time
order by m1.Time;
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4daea09613db926a2d1605f23335573)

Comment: 1th query this is only for checking the data,

Comment: 2th query, still need to use `group by` and it does not match my case, I want to calculate moving sum

Comment: I mean I still want to remain the column `Time` , I will add to my question

Comment: We could use window function with fill data technique in case missing date, but I think this is shorter, thank you. @vboka

Comment: I used this query as my Postgre SQL ver is 10